# Which is preferred: "one after another" or "one after the other"?

Tags: word-choice, idioms

Which of the following sentences is more correct or more preferred?

- Throw one die after another.
- Throw one die after the other.

As context, the sentence will be followed by

> At any time, you may stop throwing dice and finish your attempt. Your attempt must end once all eight dice have been thrown.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In that context I'd use “...after another”, as it suggests a sequence of throws.  By contrast, the “...after the other” form suggests (to me) exactly two throws, rather than some number from one to eight throws.  A useful comparison of terms similar to *consecutive* in [macmillandictionary](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/thesaurus-category/british/One-after-another) says that “one after another” indicates little time between things, which I think is sometimes true but not always.  For example, the “one after another” entry at [dictionary.cambridge.org](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/one-after-another) says “many, in a series” and makes no mention of rate.

The form “One *X* after another” refers to a series of *X*'s; as in, *eg*, [One Monster After Another](http://www.facebook.com/onemonsterafteranother), or in [Arnold Toynbee's](http://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Arnold_J._Toynbee) comment about “the dogma that History is just 'one damned thing after another....'”.

Comment: Would you say that this is also a general rule of thumb that might apply in other contexts?  (I don't have any specific examples in mind, just wondering...)

Comment: @HenryDeYoung, I added a paragraph with 2 examples